# Gradient mask for Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using `-webkit-mask-image` with the property value of `-webkit-gradient` which works perfectly in Chrome and Safari. I need the same type of effect for Firefox, I've tried to use `mask` but couldn't achieve it with `gradient`. Is it possible to use gradient mask for Firefox?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muhxqnhd/1/)

```css
h1 {
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)));
}
```

```html
<h1>I'M A GRADIENT MASK!</h1>
```

Comment: Looks like FF only supports SVGs. Not gradients `Partial support in Firefox refers to only support for inline SVG mask elements i.e. mask: url(#foo).` [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks)

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn You're right, I'm gonna try it with SVG for FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a pseudo element with a background gradient

```css
h1 {
  position:relative;
  }
h1:before {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  content:'';  
  background:linear-gradient(to top, transparent ,rgba(255,255,255,0.8),transparent );
  pointer-events:none; /* make sure it doesn't come in the way */
}
```

```html
<h1>AM I A GRADIENT MASK?!</h1>
```

Comment: What if the background is not the same as the gradient color? http://jsfiddle.net/muhxqnhd/3/

Comment: @Nima , hmmm funny , i thought mask-image and background-clip:text; were 2 different things ...

Comment: background-clip is included in mask-image, it adds the color to the text. https://jsfiddle.net/muhxqnhd/5/

Comment: @Nima well where i get confuse is how is mask-image in HTML  is using  text for a shape and not image itself, here a gradient , it could be a png or gif of any shapes (excuse my average english)

Comment: @Nima this is what i mean : http://jsfiddle.net/muhxqnhd/6/ should be one or the other to make sens of a use.

Comment: Very interesting that is. Well I guess I can't achieve the exact effect of as -webkit-mask-image  and its flexibility for FF. Thanks!